# bash syntax error near unexpected token

Tags: bash

I put a script to alert me when any new ssh connection via telegram at /etc/profile.d.
But when I connect it says:
syntax error near unexpected token
what's the problem?
my Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Import credentials form config file
. /home/roots/credentials.config
URL="https://api.telegram.org/bot${KEY}/sendMessage"
DATE="$(date "+%d %b %Y %H:%M")"
if [ -n "$SSH_CLIENT" ]; then
ip="$(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | cut -d " " -f 1)"
coinfo=($(curl ipinfo.io/${ip}/country))
rinfo=($(curl ipinfo.io/${ip}/region))
cinfo=($(curl ipinfo.io/${ip}/city))"
tinfo=($(curl ipinfo.io/${ip}/timezone))
TEXT="New login via ssh. user name: ${USER}. IP: (*${ip}*)
date: ${DATE}
Approximate location: country ${coinfo}
Region: ${rinfo}
city: ${cinfo}
time zone: ${tinfo}
Note: Location data is approximate."
curl -s -d "chat_id=${USERID}&text=${TEXT}&disable_web_page_preview=true&parse_mode=markdown" $URL > /dev/null
fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doulbe quote is placed wrongly. Even the syntax highlighter here shows it:

```
cinfo=($(curl ipinfo.io/${ip}/city))"
#                                   ~
```